# Boot2docker on windows got "Permission denied" error

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, docker, paas, boot2docker

I downloaded and installed docker-install v1.1.2 from https://github.com/boot2docker/windows-installer/releases.

However I can't start it, keep getting the "Permission denied" error:

```
C:\apps\Boot2Docker>bash
luog@IKARI:/c/apps/Boot2Docker$ ./start.sh
initializing...
./start.sh: line 21: ./boot2docker.exe: Permission denied
starting...
./start.sh: line 23: ./boot2docker.exe: Permission denied
connecting...
./start.sh: line 25: ./boot2docker.exe: Permission denied
```

If I run boot2docker directly from cmd console I got this:

```
C:\apps\Boot2Docker>boot2docker.exe
Access is denied.
```

Any idea?

**Note** I opened the cmd with administrator role, still doesn't help

The screenshot when I double click on "start.sh" from explorer:
[image]

Comment: What's in your .bashrc? Try to backup and remove it first.

Comment: Reinstall boot2docker using admin role

Answer (score 0):

From the description, it looks like two issues

**Permission**

You can run boot2docker windows installer in admin role, which can solve permission issues

**mount command**

There are some scripts in your `~/.bashrc`, it will be executed before `start.sh` since it is a bash script, suggest to temple remove it (backup first), if there is `http_proxy` kind of setting, you can keep them

Will be nice to remove `~/.boot2docker` to have clean installation especially if you have installed before.

Answer (score 0):

The version you just downloaded is not a stable version as it was release 28 days ago only

So completely **uninstall Boot2Docker** and **delete all the files related to it**.

**Restart everything**

and then download Boot2docker v1.1.1 and not v 1.1.2 from:

https://github.com/boot2docker/windows-installer/releases/download/v1.1.1/docker-install.exe

and then use this guide to install it :

http://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/

**NOTE :::** Your processor needs to support hardware virtualization.

**Let me know if this worked or else I will suggest you something else..**